# Downloading Mountain Lion

Tags: windows-7, windows, osx-lion, download

I bought Mountain Lion from Applestore last month and was under the impression that I would get a DVD in the mail. Well I read the email received from apple yesterday and I huess I was confused. My problem is that I do not have a MAc to download the software.

Am I correct to assume that the OS can only be downloaded using a Mac from the mac store?

Comment: If you don't have a Mac to install it on, that would suggest your are making a Hackintosh; which isn't covered on this forum, as it is not legal.

Comment: If you don't have a Mac how did you purchase it through the apple store in the first place?  More importantly why did you buy it knowing you didn't have an apple?

Comment: @Tetsujin Legal or not is hardly relevant here, as international laws differ. The main issue is that OS X is not supported on non-Apple hardware, so we can't help people with it.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your talking about [this](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion).

Product Information

Overview

If you need to purchase Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, you may order it from this page.
The most current version of OS X is OS X 10.9 Mavericks. To learn more, please click here.

What do you receive: An email with a **content code** for the Mac App Store.

Note: Redemption codes are usually delivered within 1 business day but may occasionally take longer.

Content codes are usually delivered within 1 business day but may occasionally take longer. The use of content codes and redeemed software is subject to the terms and conditions of the Mac App Store.

So  clearly, you're not going to get a DVD of any kind, but a code to activate your software.

> Am I correct to assume that the OS can only be downloaded using a Mac from the mac store?

Yes, I would say so, unless you call them specifically request they send a disc of some kind because you don't have internet access. But these days, I doubt that will happen. Worth a try.